# Find tag name of svg element using D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have few thousands of svg rect elements as nodes and svg path elements as links and many more such elements on UI.
Due to some user operation, some particular class get assigned to some elements.
I need to find the tag name of elements having the particular class.

In the below code i need to find element's exact tag name which have class xyz, instead of their class name or other attribute values.

```js
d3.selectAll(".xyz").each(function(){
console.log(":::: " + d3.select(this).attr("class"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
<rect class='xyz'  width="50" height="50" fill='teal'></rect>
 <line class='xyz' x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
<svg>
```

Comment: You can use `d3.selectAll('rect.xyz')` to select `rect` with class `xyz`. More details is here http://d3indepth.com/selections/

Comment: Actually I need to select all elements having the particular class and perform operations according to tag name, instead of selecting according to tag. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName).

Here is the demo using your snippet:

```js
d3.selectAll(".xyz").each(function() {
  console.log(d3.select(this).node().tagName);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
<rect class='xyz'  width="50" height="50" fill='teal'></rect>
 <line class='xyz' x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
<svg>
```

Pay attention to the fact that you have to call `tagName` on the DOM element itself, not on the D3 selection (hence `node()`). Therefore, you can use simply `this`:

```js
d3.selectAll(".xyz").each(function() {
  console.log(this.tagName);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
<rect class='xyz'  width="50" height="50" fill='teal'></rect>
 <line class='xyz' x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
<svg>
```